# Мерцание подменяемых изображений в map aria в mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, html, map, firefox

Есть скрипт на подмену и прелод изображений. Есть map area, с координатами нужных ссылок. В хроме, опере, сафари подмена изображений происходит четко. В мозилле при первом маусовере на любую ссылку с мап (и соответственно первой  подменой изображения в заданной области) очень явно мерцает фоновое изображение. При последующей наводке мерцание пропадает, пока не почистить кеш браузера. Как решить эту проблему с мозиллой? Возможно прелоад не работает? Как вариант создавались скрытые div'ы с этими изображениями, чтобы тоже подгрузить, но не помогает. Карта создавалась в fireworks, скрипты на подмену использовались и оттуда(стандартные дримвиверские).

JS:

```
function ChangeImg() {
    if (document.images) {
        eval("document." + ChangeImg.arguments[0] +
            ".src=('" + ChangeImg.arguments[1] + "')");
    }
}

function preload() {
    if (document.images) {
        var imgsrc = preload.arguments;
        arr = new Array(imgsrc.length);
        for (var j = 0; j < imgsrc.length; j++) {
            arr[j] = new Image;
            arr[j].src = imgsrc[j];
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<body onload="preload('img/bus_s3.png','img/bus.png','img/bus_s4.png',
   'img/bus_s5.png','img/bus_s6.png','img/bus_s2.png','img/bus_s7.png',
   'img/bus_bg.png')">
   <img name="bus_bg" src="img/bus_bg.png" width="1175" height="457"
      id="bus_bg" usemap="#m_bus_bg" alt="" />
   <div class="bus_bg">
      <map name="m_bus_bg" id="m_bus_bg">
         <area shape="poly"
            coords="81,13,91,11,104,10,114,11,119,15,120,21,120,32,120,40,118,49,111,53,99,53,90,53,84,52,78,48,77,41,78,31,78,21,79,15,81,13"
            href="#speakers" class="open_bus_pop" alt=""
            onmouseover="ChangeImg('bus_bg','img/bus_s2.png')"
            onmouseout="ChangeImg('bus_bg', 'img/bus_bg.png')"    />
         <area shape="poly"
            coords="447,13,457,11,469,10,480,11,484,15,486,21,486,32,486,40,484,49,477,53,465,53,455,53,450,52,444,48,443,41,443,31,443,21,445,15,447,13"
            href="#speakers" class="open_bus_pop" alt=""
            onmouseover="ChangeImg('bus_bg','img/bus_s2.png')"
            onmouseout="ChangeImg('bus_bg','img/bus_bg.png')"   />
         <area shape="poly"
            coords="826,12,836,10,848,9,859,10,863,14,865,20,865,31,865,39,863,48,856,52,844,52,834,52,829,51,823,47,822,40,822,30,822,20,824,14,826,12"
            href="#speakers" class="open_bus_pop" alt="" 
            onmouseover="ChangeImg('bus_bg','img/bus_s2.png')"onmouseout="ChangeImg('bus_bg','img/bus_bg.png')"
            />
         <area shape="poly"
            coords="1095,34,1095,44,1098,55,1104,66,1112,73,1123,79,1135,81,1143,80,1152,77,1163,70,1168,63,1172,54,1175,43,1175,32,1171,23,1165,13,1154,5,1146,2,1139,0,1130,0,1121,3,1113,7,1105,14,1099,21,1096,27,1095,34"
            href="#server" class="open_bus_pop" alt=""  
            onmouseover="ChangeImg('bus_bg','img/bus_s3.png')"
            onmouseout="ChangeImg('bus_bg','img/bus_bg.png')"   />
         <area shape="poly"
            coords="1001,139,1001,145,1000,157,1000,174,1000,187,1002,191,1010,193,1016,192,1020,192,1023,195,1023,197,1024,201,1026,204,1034,206,1039,206,1043,205,1046,200,1046,200,1049,194,1051,191,1056,191,1065,192,1073,192,1077,192,1079,189,1080,170,1080,156,1080,152,1084,146,1085,141,1086,134,1085,130,1083,126,1079,123,1074,120,1067,120,1064,120,1060,122,1055,125,1053,129,1053,129,1051,133,1051,136,1048,136,1035,137,1024,137,1013,138,1008,138,1003,138,1001,139"
            href="#leptop" class="open_bus_pop" alt="" 
            onmouseover="ChangeImg('bus_bg','img/bus_s4.png')"
            onmouseout="ChangeImg('bus_bg','img/bus_bg.png')"   />
         <area shape="poly"
            coords="1035,281,1033,275,1032,270,1032,263,1032,257,1032,250,1035,249,1040,249,1048,249,1057,249,1059,251,1060,257,1059,265,1059,272,1057,280,1053,282,1048,283,1048,286,1048,288,1045,289,1043,288,1043,285,1043,283,1042,283,1038,282,1035,281"
            href="#load" class="open_bus_pop" alt=""
            onmouseover="ChangeImg('bus_bg','img/bus_s5.png')"
            onmouseout="ChangeImg('bus_bg','img/bus_bg.png')"    />
         <area shape="poly"
            coords="878,248,878,251,878,255,878,261,878,267,878,275,879,285,880,289,886,292,894,292,901,292,909,293,916,293,922,292,925,290,928,287,929,282,928,272,929,260,929,250,927,245,923,242,912,241,898,241,890,241,885,241,882,243,878,248"
            href="#amplifier" class="open_bus_pop" alt="" 
            onmouseover="ChangeImg('bus_bg','img/bus_s6.png')"
            onmouseout="ChangeImg('bus_bg','img/bus_bg.png')"   />
         <area shape="poly"
            coords="793,188,792,183,792,179,792,173,792,167,792,149,792,135,792,130,794,127,803,126,827,126,852,126,867,126,878,127,880,129,880,131,881,150,881,168,880,184,879,188,878,189,878,189,867,190,856,190,849,190,849,196,852,197,854,200,851,203,837,203,823,204,819,201,819,197,821,196,823,196,823,195,823,192,823,191,821,189,814,189,805,189,794,189,793,188"
            href="#monitor" class="open_bus_pop" alt="" 
            onmouseover="ChangeImg('bus_bg','img/bus_s7.png')"
            onmouseout="ChangeImg('bus_bg','img/bus_bg.png')"   />
      </map>
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог данный скрипт. При загрузки страницы изображение в мозилле перестало мерцать. Однако, начинает мерцать спустя какое-то время, если долго страницу не обновлять, но это уже нюансы.

```
<script>
    function init() {
        // quit if this function has already been called
        if (arguments.callee.done) return;

        // flag this function so we don't do the same thing twice
        arguments.callee.done = true;

        // preload images
        preload([
            'img/bus_bg.png',
            'img/bus_s2.png',
            'img/bus_s3.png',
            'img/bus_s4.png',
            'img/bus_s5.png',
            'img/bus_s6.png',
            'img/bus_s7.png'
        ]);
    };

    /* for Mozilla */
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
    }

    /* for other browsers */
    window.onload = init;

    function preload(images) {
        if (typeof document.body == "undefined") return;
        try {

            var div = document.createElement("div");
            var s = div.style;
                s.position = "absolute";
            s.top = s.left = 0;
            s.visibility = "hidden";
            document.body.appendChild(div);
            div.innerHTML = "<img src=\"" + images.join("\" /><img src=\"") + "\" />";
            var lastImg = div.lastChild;
            lastImg.onload = function() { document.body.removeChild(document.body.lastChild); };
        }
        catch(e) {
            // Error. Do nothing.
        }
    }
</script>
```